# Application not responding after integrating Firebase Crash Reporting

Tags: android, firebase, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gallery, firebase-crash-reporting

I've integrated Firebase recently to track the crashes in the application.

After integrating that, Application is not getting the control back from the gallery app after selecting a picture. I see a black screen after selecting the picture and after few seconds OS is showing ANR.

I see that there's another process being spawned by Firebase, and my GUESS is that the OS is not able to figure out to which process it must return the data.

If I remove Firebase integration, then everything works fine.

Below are the logs from the device :

```
06-09 22:26:28.330: I/ActivityManager(781): START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10829 on display 0
06-09 22:26:28.357: I/ActivityManager(781): Start proc 26257:com.android.packageinstaller/u0a60 for activity com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity
06-09 22:26:28.395: W/System(26257): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/GooglePackageInstaller/lib/arm
06-09 22:26:28.460: D/OpenGLRenderer(26257): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-09 22:26:28.498: I/Adreno-EGL(26257): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 09/02/15, 76f806e, Ibddc658e36
06-09 22:26:28.498: E/linker(26257): readlink('/proc/self/fd/26') failed: Permission denied [fd=26]
06-09 22:26:28.498: E/linker(26257): warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/vendor/lib/egl/eglsubAndroid.so". Will use given name.
06-09 22:26:28.499: I/OpenGLRenderer(26257): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-09 22:26:28.567: I/ActivityManager(781): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity: +228ms
06-09 22:26:28.597: I/art(781): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 118272(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 38(824KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 32MB/48MB, paused 2.272ms total 132.018ms
06-09 22:26:30.598: D/VoldConnector(781): SND -> {13 volume remount_uid 10829 read}
06-09 22:26:30.611: D/vold(148): Remounting 10829 as mode read
06-09 22:26:30.617: D/vold(148): Found matching PID 25188
06-09 22:26:30.621: D/VoldConnector(781): RCV <- {200 13 Command succeeded}
06-09 22:26:30.622: D/VoldConnector(781): SND -> {14 volume remount_uid 10829 write}
06-09 22:26:30.622: D/vold(148): Remounting 10829 as mode write
06-09 22:26:30.629: D/vold(148): Found matching PID 25188
06-09 22:26:30.638: D/VoldConnector(781): RCV <- {200 14 Command succeeded}
06-09 22:26:30.663: I/ActivityManager(781): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.PICK dat=content://media/external/images/media cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity} from uid 10829 on display 0
06-09 22:26:30.672: E/Surface(26257): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaed46330
06-09 22:26:30.676: D/OpenGLRenderer(26257): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb3c1cb80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xacbcef10
06-09 22:26:30.698: I/ActivityManager(781): Start proc 26286:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a658 for activity com.google.android.apps.photos/.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity
06-09 22:26:30.722: I/ActivityManager(781): Killing 24579:com.android.defcontainer/u0a4 (adj 15): empty #17
06-09 22:26:30.778: E/Surface(25188): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x91e83680
06-09 22:26:30.865: W/SurfaceFlinger(196): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-09 22:26:30.897: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 56
06-09 22:26:30.897: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:26:31.476: W/TrustedPartners(26286): no provider found for com.motorola.camera.provider.bestshotprovider.BestShotProvider; do not trust
06-09 22:26:31.477: W/TrustedPartners(26286): no provider found for com.google.android.apps.photos.api.SpecialTypesProvider; do not trust
06-09 22:26:31.477: W/TrustedPartners(26286): no provider found for com.lge.photos.specialtypeprovider; do not trust
06-09 22:26:31.746: D/OpenGLRenderer(26286): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-09 22:26:31.798: I/Adreno-EGL(26286): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 09/02/15, 76f806e, Ibddc658e36
06-09 22:26:31.798: E/linker(26286): readlink('/proc/self/fd/32') failed: Permission denied [fd=32]
06-09 22:26:31.798: E/linker(26286): warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/vendor/lib/egl/eglsubAndroid.so". Will use given name.
06-09 22:26:31.799: I/OpenGLRenderer(26286): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-09 22:26:31.832: W/ActivityManager(781): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.google.android.music/com.google.android.music.dial.DialMediaRouteProviderService} from pid=26286, uid=10658 that is not exported from uid 10058
06-09 22:26:32.010: I/ActivityManager(781): Displayed com.google.android.apps.photos/.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity: +1s322ms
06-09 22:26:32.048: D/FirebaseApp(25188): Notifying background state change listeners.
06-09 22:26:32.563: D/MdnsClient(1437): Multicast lock held. Releasing
06-09 22:26:32.569: D/MdnsClient(1437): #acquireLock. Multicast lock not held. Acquiring
06-09 22:26:33.128: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=170166597, 192.168.1.1, [48F8B350AC2B], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
06-09 22:26:33.670: D/WifiStateMachine(781): starting scan for "CISCO"WPA_PSK with 2462
06-09 22:26:33.950: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 60
06-09 22:26:33.951: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:26:35.809: I/ActivityManager(781): START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.apps.photos/.localmedia.ui.LocalPhotosActivity (has extras)} from uid 10658 on display 0
06-09 22:26:36.123: I/ActivityManager(781): Displayed com.google.android.apps.photos/.localmedia.ui.LocalPhotosActivity: +292ms
06-09 22:26:36.160: D/OpenGLRenderer(26286): endAllStagingAnimators on 0x9ca73780 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb073eac0
06-09 22:26:36.185: I/iu.UploadsManager(1437): #reloadSettings(); account: -1; IU: disabled; IS: disabled; IS account: -1; photoWiFi: true; videoWiFi: true; roam: false; battery: true; size: STANDARD; maxMobile: 157286400
06-09 22:26:36.190: I/iu.UploadsManager(1437): #reloadSettings(); account: -1; IU: disabled; IS: disabled; IS account: -1; photoWiFi: true; videoWiFi: true; roam: false; battery: true; size: STANDARD; maxMobile: 157286400
06-09 22:26:36.350: W/SurfaceFlinger(196): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-09 22:26:38.600: E/Surface(26286): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9cc29ce0
06-09 22:26:38.823: W/SurfaceFlinger(196): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
06-09 22:26:39.984: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 56
06-09 22:26:39.984: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:26:42.039: W/ActivityManager(781): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{30e699a u0 com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity t108}
06-09 22:26:42.039: I/ActivityManager(781): Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{30e699a u0 com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity t108}
06-09 22:26:43.038: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 60
06-09 22:26:43.039: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:26:43.951: I/InputDispatcher(781): Dropping event because there is no touchable window at (355, 1421).
06-09 22:26:48.424: W/ActivityManager(781): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-09 22:26:53.674: D/WifiStateMachine(781): starting scan for "CISCO"WPA_PSK with 2462
06-09 22:26:55.149: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 56
06-09 22:26:55.149: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:26:58.180: D/ConnectivityService(781): updateNetworkScore for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228] to 60
06-09 22:26:58.180: D/ConnectivityService(781): rematching NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 228]
06-09 22:27:01.099: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=170194567, 192.168.1.1, [48F8B350AC2B], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}
06-09 22:27:13.674: D/WifiStateMachine(781): starting scan for "CISCO"WPA_PSK with 2462
06-09 22:27:15.329: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=170208797, 192.168.1.1, [48F8B350AC2B], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_STALE}
06-09 22:27:15.629: I/InputDispatcher(781): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{7c00aa8 token=Token{86c12cb ActivityRecord{30e699a u0 com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity t108}}}.  It has been 5014.1ms since event, 5006.0ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.
06-09 22:27:15.645: I/WindowManager(781): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{7c00aa8 token=Token{86c12cb ActivityRecord{30e699a u0 com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity t108}}}.  Reason: Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.
06-09 22:27:15.703: W/InputDispatcher(781): Asynchronous input event injection timed out.
06-09 22:27:15.718: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 25188 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:15.719: I/art(25188): Thread[2,tid=25193,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee14000,peer=0x32c080a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:15.918: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 781 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:15.919: I/art(781): Thread[2,tid=786,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c010a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:16.008: I/art(25188): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:17.412: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 1374 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:17.412: I/art(1374): Thread[2,tid=1381,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c5a0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:17.412: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 1361 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:17.414: I/art(1361): Thread[2,tid=1366,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c5a0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:17.561: I/art(1361): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:17.561: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 1284 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:17.561: I/art(1284): Thread[2,tid=1290,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c4b0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:17.629: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 921 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:17.629: I/art(921): Thread[2,tid=926,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c2c0a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:17.629: I/art(1284): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:17.756: I/art(1374): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:17.812: I/art(781): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:17.925: I/art(921): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:19.665: I/Process(781): Sending signal. PID: 1629 SIG: 3
06-09 22:27:19.665: I/art(1629): Thread[2,tid=1634,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee0b000,peer=0x12c650a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): ANR in com.vari.in (com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity)
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): PID: 25188
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): Load: 9.85 / 9.34 / 9.63
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): CPU usage from 47812ms to 0ms ago:
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   5.1% 781/system_server: 3.5% user + 1.5% kernel / faults: 4459 minor 9 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   2.6% 196/surfaceflinger: 0.9% user + 1.7% kernel / faults: 61 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.7% 25188/com.vari.in: 0.6% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 2120 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.7% 2055/mpdecision: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.6% 921/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 115 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.3% 124/dhd_dpc: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 24675/android.process.media: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1437 minor 2 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.3% 120/mmcqd/1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.3% 211/sensors.qcom: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 25 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.2% 1629/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1912 minor 1 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.2% 22651/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.2% 22672/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 55/kswapd0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 1437/com.google.android.gms: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1515 minor 15 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 15372/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 7/kworker/u:0H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 131/ueventd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 1073/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0.1% 335/mdss_fb0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 96/irq/362-s3350: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 24701/com.google.android.apps.plus: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1158 minor 7 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 123/dhd_watchdog_th: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 138/jbd2/mmcblk0p28: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 147/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 202/rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 215/zygote: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2347 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 10251/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 13919/com.google.process.gapps: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 598 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 24036/kworker/u:5: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 24066/com.estrongs.android.pop: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 26 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 25851/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 2/kthreadd: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 8/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 126/dhd_sysioc: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 136/flush-179:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 148/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 104 minor 3 major
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 194/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 195/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 208/bridgemgrd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 73 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 209/qmuxd: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 214/thermal-engine-hh: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 1374/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 68 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 14798/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 25894/com.google.android.youtube: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 274 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 26177/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 26230/kworker/0:2H: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   0% 26248/kworker/0:3H: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):  +0% 26255/kworker/u:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):  +0% 26257/com.android.packageinstaller: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):  +0% 26286/com.google.android.apps.photos: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): 15% TOTAL: 9% user + 5% kernel + 1.3% iowait + 0.1% softirq
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): CPU usage from 3372ms to 3897ms later:
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   10% 781/system_server: 6.9% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):     10% 795/ActivityManager: 6.9% user + 3.4% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):     1.7% 781/system_server: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):     1.7% 829/system_server: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   1.4% 1629/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 1.4% user + 0% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   1.4% 2055/mpdecision: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):     1.4% 2072/mpdecision: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781):   1.5% 10251/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.880: E/ActivityManager(781): 5.6% TOTAL: 3.7% user + 1.8% kernel
06-09 22:27:19.901: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0xc8, repeatCount=1, eventTime=8907676, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.902: W/ViewRootImpl(781): Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=8912255, downTime=8907167, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
06-09 22:27:19.944: I/OpenGLRenderer(781): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-09 22:27:20.117: D/DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService(1437): User is not opted-in to Usage & Diagnostics.
06-09 22:27:20.135: I/art(1629): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 22:27:22.538: D/NetlinkSocketObserver(781): NeighborEvent{elapsedMs=170216007, 192.168.1.1, [48F8B350AC2B], RTM_NEWNEIGH, NUD_PROBE}
```

Comment: Firebase Crash Reporting does start a service in a new process when it's trying to transmit a crash, but I don't see any reference to it here.  The process is called "background_crash".  What I do see is ANR for "Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{30e699a u0 com.vari.in/.ui.activities.PostAdActivity". Could you take a look there?

Comment: I am getting that ANR because the activity is not getting the control back after selecting the image, and the logs i put in "onActivityResult" callback are not getting printed. And yes, the process firebase is starting is {application_id}:background_crash, which is spawned when the application is launched.

Comment: The typical case of an ANR is that something on the main thread is blocking for more than 5 seconds.  Other processes wouldn't have any direct effect on that.  Where in your logs do you see anything about the crash reporting process or its services?  I just don't see anything here.  Without seeing your code or more detailed stack traces, I don't think there is anything I can do the help.